# React dynamic image path causes refetch

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a components which renders one dynamic image, meaning its `src` is set based on a changing state. Every time I change the state, the browser refetches the same images over and over again. Can I use some caching here? Does anyone have a smart way of using already fetched images?

```
const imagePaths = [
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/IPA_Unicode_0x0061.svg/180px-IPA_Unicode_0x0061.svg.png',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575936123452-b67c3203c357?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aW1hZ2V8ZW58MHx8MHx8fDA%3D&w=1000&q=80'
]

function App() {
  const [flip, setFlip] = useState(false)
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setFlip(prev => !prev)}>Flip</button>
      <img width={200} src={flip ? imagePaths[0] : imagePaths[1]} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tested it and it caches the image. It's probably happening on your end because your dev environment has cache disabled.

Comment: Check this [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-microservice-7k9cgv). It doesn't happen. It seems your dev env's cache got disabled.

Comment: Thank you, you we're right! Do people rely on this caching always or is there a common programmatic approach that I haven't seen?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone seeing this, as technophyle pointed out, check for any disabled cache in browser.

If somehow caching is not an option, I did this as an easy workaround. Just let two `img`'s flip between `hidden` and not

```
<img width={200} hidden={!flip} src={imagePaths[0]} />
<img width={200} hidden={flip} src={imagePaths[1]} />
```